# USB 3.0 Raspberry Pi 4 B data rate

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, data-transfer, usb3

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 B.

When I plug the ethernet cable to the ethernet connection, I get speeds close to 1 Gbps as expected.

Nevertheless, when I plug an USB3.0 cable I get a maximum of 400 Mbps when supossed to get speed close to 5 Gbps because of USB3.0. Which could be the problem?

Comment: What's on the other end of the USB 3 cable? What type of data transfer are you trying?

Comment: That figure (400 mbps) sounds quite normal for the Rpi4. The figure of 5 Gbit/s is a theoretical maximum. Sustained transfer speeds (real life) for external hard drives can reach about 800 Mbps for suitable hardware (at both ends of the cable) and the RPi is not the fastest.

Comment: In the other end of the USB3 there is a card supposed to transfer via radio 800 Mbps. Nevertheless, the measured speed on the USB3 is not more than 400 Mbps.

Answer (score 1):

#### *"Let me google that for you:"*

You can find much information online re the architecture of the RPi 4; e.g. [**this search**](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=Raspberry+Pi+4B+network+speeds&atb=v278-1&ia=web). Two credible blog posts from the same author that address your questions are these:

- [Re performance of the in-built (Broadcom) Ethernet controller](https://tomcore.io/docs/articles/RaspberryPI/raspberry-pi-4b-network-performance/). IIRC, the 4B was considered a vast improvement in Ethernet BW over earlier models. There were numerous reviews posted ca. RPi 4B production release in the usual archives (Tom'sHardware, etc).
- [Re performance of the USB Network Performance](https://tomcore.io/docs/articles/RaspberryPI/raspberry-pi-4b-usb-network-performance/). My *takeaway* from this post is that the BW you will see are dependent on which adapter and driver you choose.

These two articles not only provide some answers to your query, but they also document the methods used to conduct the test - this allows **you** to run the tests under the conditions that best represent **your** intended usage. That's always a "good thing" because performance tests are invariably influenced strongly by the test methods.